# Programmatically formatting string in swift

Tags: macos, swift

I have strings

```
var arrayWithStrings = ["813 - Crying Flute.mp3", "Ark Patrol - Never.mp3"]
```

I want to get

```
var stringTitle1 = "813"
var stringNameOfTrack1 = "CryingFlute"
var stringFormat1 = "mp3"
var stringTitle2 = "Ark Patrol"
var stringNameOfTrack2 = "Never"
var stringFormat2 = "mp3"
```

How to do it programmatically?

Comment: You can use Regular Expression to match every element in the array as you want.

Comment: @Rob No, i need to get it from array elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
let string = "813 - Crying Flute.mp3"

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^(.*) - (.*)\\.(.*)$")

if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: string, range: string.nsRange) {
    let title  = string[match.range(at: 1)]
    let name   = string[match.range(at: 2)]
    let format = string[match.range(at: 3)]
}
```

Where, in Swift 4:

```
extension String {

    /// An `NSRange` that represents the full range of the string.

    var nsRange: NSRange {
        return NSRange(startIndex ..< endIndex, in: self)
    }

    /// Substring from `NSRange`
    ///
    /// - Parameter nsRange: `NSRange` within the string.
    /// - Returns: `Substring` with the given `NSRange`, or `nil` if the range can't be converted.

    subscript(nsRange: NSRange) -> Substring? {
        return Range(nsRange, in: self)
            .flatMap { self[$0] }
    }
}
```

The regular expression's `(` and `)` are "capturing parentheses" to identify the substrings, that can be identified by `range(at:)`.

Comment: @Rob I though you have an error in the pattern , it should be `"^(.*) - (.*)\\.(.*)$"` because the beginning isn't always a number, it could be letters regarding the array in the question

Comment: Good catch. Thanks. I was just focusing on the first example.